# Display Related Data in Popups for Grouped Layers

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, relates, arcade, feature-set

I am creating a web map from a map service that contains related data. I want to display the related data in my point feature popups. I thought it would be easy to pull in the related tables in Arcade using the FeatureSetBy functions, but the globals ($datastore, $map) are not available because the layers are grouped.

Is there another way to pull the related data tables using Arcade?

I cannot use FeatureSetbyPortalID because of my organization's permissions. I tried adding the layers individually so I could access the globals, but this created issues with the popups not loading for features with related data once a web app was created from the web map. I am aware of and don't want to use the "Show Related Records" feature at the bottom of the popups. The web app's target audience will not necessarily be tech-savvy or have experience with GIS and so we want the related data to be simply displayed within the text of the popups.